# Is Window.Close() synchronous in WPF?

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, window

As the title states, I was wondering if the the Close() method on a window is synchronous or not.

I browsed msdn but was unable to find an answer.

Thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 4):

`Window.Close()` is synchronous in WPF.

You can test easily enough by adding event handlers to the `Closing` or `Closed` events, and trace the execution:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    Debug.WriteLine("Closing");
    this.Closing += OnClosing;
    this.Closed += OnClosed;
    this.Close();
    Debug.WriteLine("Closed");
}

private void OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("In OnClosed");
}

private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs cancelEventArgs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("In OnClosing");
}
```

This will print out:

```
Closing
In OnClosing
In OnClosed
Closed
```